# Flask Bcrypt password hash doesn’t match, How to solve it?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, bcrypt

I am trying to make a simple web app using Flask. And I tried to run it with sqlite. And it works perfectly. The only problem is when I tried to host the app on a Shared hosting server,with MySQL as the database, I've faced some password matching issues. When I lookup at the problem, I saw flask-bcrypt password hashes aren’t matching.   And I Don't know how to fix it. Here is the code :

```
from flask_bcrypt import Bcrypt

app.config["SECRET_KEY"] = "super-secret-key"
cryptor = Bcrypt(app)
```

#### Hashing and storing in database:

**Note:** I've tried to match passwords using the Terminal & Interpreter before storing on database. And it matched, But once stored and pulled back it doesn’t match.

```
password = cryptor.generate_password_hash(request.form.get("password")).decode("utf-8")

user_obj = Users(password=password)
db.session.add(user_obj)
db.session.commit()
```

#### Matching:

```
data = Users.query.filter_by(email=form.username.data).first()
if cryptor.check_password_hash(data.password, form.password.data):
    #pass the login check
else:
    #dont pass
```

#### Sqlalchemy model:

```
class Users(db.model):
    password = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing this:

```
class Users(db.model):
    password = db.Column(db.String(50), nullable=False)
```

to this:

```
class Users(db.model):
    password = db.Column(db.String(X), nullable=False)
```

(X = the length of the hashed password)

When you specify 50 you are telling the database to reserve a space for 50 characters, which cuts off most of the hashed password when you store it. Increasing the space reserved will allow you to verify the hash. Refer to [Flask SQLAlchemy Docs.](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/models/)

The reason why you did not have any problems with Sqlite is because its optional to specify the maximum length of the string. (Same goes for PostgreSQL)